# Skipping int 0 skips False too

Tags: python

I got list of integers and keywords 
and i'm trying to remove only `zeros` from list with for loop - continue, but keyword `False` removes too, and how to prevent removing `False` ? ? ?

```py
a = [1,2,0,1,0,1,None,0,False]

for x in a:
    if x ==0:
        continue
```

Comment: You could convert it to `str(x)` for the comparison

Comment: A better approach is `type(x) is int` or `x == 0 and x is not False`

Comment: ^ no, a better approach would be `not (isinstance(x, int) and x == 0)`

Comment: `str(x)` is atrocious (false positive on the string `'0'`, for starters). `type(x) is int` works, but only if you do not expect floats (0.0 will not be matched) or subclasses of int. The `isinstance` way fails because `isinstance(False, int)` is `True` (booleans are a subclass of integers). In short: go see the duplicate, where the accepted answer is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare to exactly `0` use the `is` keyword:

```
a = [1,2,0,1,0,1,None,0,False]

for x in a: 
    if x is 0:
        continue
    print(x)
```

Comment: -1 because although in works in that exact case (on the standard Python implementation), it will fail with no apparent reason when the value to compare to is a different integer or a float. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: Thank you it works good,  Suddenly i could not think about keyword is to use,